# Search and replace in a range of line and column

Tags: regex, vim

I want to apply a search and replace regular expression pattern that work only in a given range of line and column on a text file like this :

```
AAABBBFFFFBBBAAABBB
AAABBBFFFFBBBAAABBB
GGGBBBFFFFBHHAAABBB
```

For example i want to replace BBB with YYY in line range 1 to 2 and from column 4 to 6, then obtaining this output :

```
AAAYYYFFFFBBBAAABBB
AAAYYYFFFFBBBAAABBB
GGGBBBFFFFBHHAAABBB
```

Is there a way to do it with Vim ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
:1,2 s/\%3cBBB/YYY/
```

`\%3c` means third column (see `:help /\%c` or more globally `:help pattern`)

Comment: The column is the fourth :    :1,2s/\%4cBBB/YYY/

Answer (score 4):

If this is always the first one you want to replace, simply don't specify /g

```
:1,2s/BBB/YYY/
```

would work fine.

Alternatively, if you need to exactly specify which column you want replaced, you can use the `\%Nv` syntax, where N is the virtual column (column as it looks, so tabs are multiple columns, use c instead of v for actual columns)

Replacing the second set of B's on lines 1 and 2 could be done with:

```
:1,2s/\%11vBBB/YYY/
```

Comment: `\%v` vs `\%c`… up to him to tell us.

Answer (score 0):

Specifying rows and columns `:1,2s/\%>3c\%<7cB/Y/gc`

Answer (score 0):

Also works:

```
:%s/\%>3c\%<7c\%>0l\%<3lB/Y/g
```

`c` for columns and `l` for lines or rows